# Quicksort on any type of list | Haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell, quicksort

I am currently learning Haskell on learnyouahaskell.com and they present us with the following quicksort algorithm for integer lists.

```
quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]    
quicksort [] = []    
quicksort (x:xs) =     
    let smallerSorted = quicksort (filter (<=x) xs)  
        biggerSorted = quicksort (filter (>x) xs)   
    in  smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```

Is there a way to modify it to accept any type of list? I was thinking of adding an extra parameter to indicate the the comparison operation to use

Comment: It already is polymorphic in the type of lists.  You can pass it any list that has an `Ord` instance (like lists of `String`, `Double`, or even `Bool`), not just `[Int]`.  You can also add an argument of type `a -> a -> Bool` -- which would be the comparison operator -- and use that in place of `<=` (and use `not` of that in place of `>`).

Comment: @DDub Thanks for the answer! In the case where we add a comparison operator, what would the expression definition become?  Would it be `quicksort :: [a] => (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] ` ?

Comment: Close!  The stuff between `::` and `=>` is "context"/"instance information".  In your original definition, this is where you demand that the type `a` have an `Ord` instance.  However, in your new version, you don't need any special context.  So, the type would be just `quicksort :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`

Comment: Compare `sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]` and `sortBy : (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]`, both defined in [`Data.List`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html). For `sort`, the type `a` brings its own comparison operators with it; for `sortBy`, you provide the comparison operator: `a` may or may not have an `Ord` instance, but if it does, it's ignored.

Answer (score 4):

You can, as you specify in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73780909/quicksort-on-any-type-of-list-haskell#comment130282314_73780909), pass a function that will determine if for example the first item is less than or equal the second item, or any other order relation.

In that case you thus can work with:

```
quicksort :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]    
quicksort _ [] = []
quicksort lte (x:xs) =
    let smallerSorted = quicksort lte (filter (`lte` x) xs)  
        biggerSorted = quicksort lte (filter … xs)
    in  smallerSorted ++ x : biggerSorted
```

For the `…` part, you will have to negate the `lte` function. I leave that as an exercise.